# What kind of sound changes when hundert followed by drei?

Tags: pronunciation, sound

I feel very odd when the guy pronouncing this word [663](https://instaud.io/2PkN), sechs**hundertdrei**und... becomes something like sechs**hund??rei**und....

I'm a beginner, so please analyze the sound change for me, thanks a lot.

EDIT:
A slow version [here](https://instaud.io/2Plh), in order to hear the detail.

Comment: It sounds completely normal to me, can you be more specific in how it differs from what you expected?

Comment: -er- in reduction syllables becomes **Tiefschwa**. You have to learn this vowel, it's everywhere. The *-dr-* also has a vocalized component of the *Tiefschwa* flavour.

Comment: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/hundert

Comment: @Carsten S To me, it should be **hundert drei**, I could accept if the "t" of hundert overlaps the "d" of drei, then it will be **hunder-drei**. But to my non-native ear, the guy pronouncing it as **hunder(t)-(d)rei**, the "t" and "d" are both omitted. It's hard to recognize.

Comment: I hear one flop of a *t*. They can be short as this.

Comment: I hear both the t and the d, but one often hears what one expects. It would be necessary to listen to bits of it in isolation. But I am just a native speaker, maybe someone with knowledge in phonetics has some insight into this.

Comment: @Janka No, that's the background noise of the recording, seems like a sound made by chair.

Comment: There's no background noise. He's clearly speaking the *t* of *-dert-* at 0:00.4

Comment: @Carsten S I've added a slow version of the audio, feel free to hear it, it may provide more details :)

Comment: @Janka Oh, I see, the "d" is the middle "d" as hun**d**ert I suppose. What I said to be omitted is the last "t" as hunder**t**.

Comment: The -ert is at 0:00.8 now. No chairs involved.

Comment: @Janka **Hundert-drei** finally becomes **hundrei**, is this a normal sound change?

Comment: I think you just fail to hear the -ert- because you think it's a chair clanking. It's not. The speaker makes that sound.

Comment: @Janka Ohhhhhh..... Seems like a consonant stop at the word ending of hunder**t**, the beginning "d" of drei is also stoped hence the result, am I right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84738/discussion-between-janka-and-preachers).

Comment: @preachers "Hundert-drei finally becomes hundrei" is not correct. Also : no chair! Consonant stop: yes! When you come from the **hunder** you effectively don't use a **t**, because you don't remove the tongue from your teeth for that hissing(?) sound of the t. You make a short stop, where you leave the tongue on the back of the teeth and start the d in the same position.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I listened to both the original and the slower version. It sounds perfectly normal to the native ear. Even analyzing sounds, every sound you would expect is there. The final **t** from hunder**t** and the first **d** from **d**rei are coalesced (so sounding a bit like sechshunder-**(td)**-reiundsechzig, but this is the correct sound). But it seems you are claiming the **er** in hun**de**rt is also missing? This is definitely not the case, all sounds are there.

Comment: No, I didn't say that, I can hear the "er" sound very clearly. Thanks for your reply, your analyze is great.